# Missing Content Web Query web part in a my-site

Tags: my-site, content-query-web-part

On [my-site](/questions/tagged/my-site) I've created a wiki site and would like to make use of [content-query-web-part](/questions/tagged/content-query-web-part), however when I `Page > Edit > Insert > Web Part` CQWP isn't among the available choices. Does it have another name? or perhaps our administrator hasn't enabled that?

I'm an end user, and the site is running SharePoint Server 2010 (according to Help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQWP is added to the list of available web parts as part of the Site Collection Feature "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure"

Go to `Site Settings | Site Collection Features` (in Site Collection Administration group). You may have to click `Site Settings | Go to top level site settings` to get to the root. In a sub-site there may another publishing feature to activate also.

After that Content Query is available at under `Edit > Insert > Web part > Content Rollup`.

Or you can save the following xml into a file called ContentQuery.webpart and the add it to your pages using "Upload a Web Part":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title" type="string">Content Query</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">Displays a dynamic view of content from your site.</property>
        <property name="ChromeType">TitleOnly</property>
        <property name="ChromeState">Normal</property>
        <property name="ItemLimit" type="int">15</property>
        <property name="SortBy" type="string">{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}</property>
        <property name="SortByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
        <property name="GroupStyle" type="string">DefaultHeader</property>
        <property name="ItemStyle" type="string">Default</property>
        <property name="ServerTemplate" type="string"></property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Comment: thanks! Since I was working on a sub-site I needed to `Site Settings > Go to top level site settings`, activate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure", followed by sub-site `Settings > SharePoint Server Publishing` [activate].

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the publishing infrastructure feature for the site for the CQWP to show up.

Comment: under `Site Settings > Features` I see "SharePoint Server Publishing", is this what you mean? In any case when I press the [activate] button I'm told *"The feature being activated is a Site scoped feature which has a dependency on a Site Collection scoped feature which has not been activated. Please activate the following feature before trying again: SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure"*, which sounds like an Admin-only thing. Is that correct?

Comment: It's a Site Collection Admin only thing, but on mysite you should be Site Collection Admin

Comment: Got it now, see comment on other answer. I had started on a sub-site instead of my root my-site. Thanks for the help.